# Ctrl+Alt+F1 shows nothing, Xubuntu 14.04.1, Macbookpro11,3 (retina, nvidia)

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or + F2-F6) shows just a black black screen (on every monitor if there are any externals), although <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> may bring the desktop back. It's a Xubuntu 14.04.1 on MacBookPro11,3 with retina and nvidia graphics.

Since blank black screen happens a lot when plug/unplug external screens, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or F2,3,4,5,6,7 etc. or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> does nothing, I can only power off if this situation happens.

Is this because the resolution stuff that stop ttys from displaying, maybe?

Update: if Nvidia driver uninstalled, tty works. When Nvidia driver installed again, blank tty again.

Update: I just reinstall Xubuntu again (not because of this issue), the system now is relatively fresh,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shows nothing (nvidia v 343 driver installed).

Comment: Can you see the top of your screen?  The tty only shows a single line of text, so if a few pixels are cut off, it could appear blank.